# How to close a view in all perspectives?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am developing an Eclipse plugin with a view. As I am performing some initialization code in `ViewPart.createPartControl`, I want to add a button to force reload the view.

I use the following code to close all instances of my view:

```java
for (IWorkbenchWindow window:  PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getWorkbenchWindows()) {
    for (IWorkbenchPage page: window.getPages()) {
        IViewReference view = getReferenceForView(page, VIEW_ID);
        page.hideView(view);
    }
}
```

The `getReferenceForView` method just gets the reference to my view in that page. Above code works fine, but only for the current perspective. Is there a way to close the view in all perspectives?

Comment: Can't you just refresh the existing view when necessary? You shouldn't need to close a view just to refresh it.

Comment: That does seem easier.. Don't know why I didn't just think of that.